# Magnetic field of a circular particle accelerator

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, particle-physics, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

Suppose there's a $500 \ GeV$ proton beam ($q=1.6 \times 10^{-19} C$) inside a circular particle accelerator, what would be the magnetic field intensity $B$ in Teslas required to keep it stable at a gyroradius of $r = 750 \ m$?

I derived the following relation from Lorent'z force and the centripetal force:

$$B = \frac{p}{rq}$$

I also used the following equation from the relativistic energy-momentum relation to find the momentum, $p$, of the proton beam:

$$\sqrt{\frac{E^2 - (m_0c^2)}{c^2}}= p$$

Carrying out substitutions and units conversions I eventually end up with an absurd $~70 \ T$ field when the answer should be $2.2 \ T$

Am I making any fundamental mistakes here?

Comment: Without seeing your work, we can't say where the mistake lies.  As 500 GeV is quite large compared to the proton rest mass, the momentum is 500 GeV/c and going through the square root is unnecessary work.

Comment: I tried it again by considering $p = 500 \frac{GeV}{c}$ as you said and it was much easier, it also became clear what I was doing wrong, I was converting the electronvolt wrong (for the energy instead of momentum). The answer was $2.2 \ T$ Thank you very much, sir.